# How to increment value stored in HashBasedTable properly?

Tags: java, collections, guava

Right now, I'm storing some numerical value as a value of HashBasedTable. When I want to change its amount I need to write something like:

```
table.put("AS", "BS", table.get("AS", "BS") == null? 123: table.get("AS", "BS")+123);
```

Which in my perception seems quite messy... Is there any other way to handle it properly? I mean without null checking, getting out of map and putting it back again.
Maybe you can suggest any other data type instead of Guava table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's roughly the way to go with `Table` interface, although I'd use [`firstNonNull(T, T)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v18.0/javadoc/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html#firstNonNull(T,%20T)) to avoid calling get twice:

```
Table<String, String, Integer> table = HashBasedTable.create();
table.put("AS", "X", 2);
// with null check
table.put("AS", "BS", Objects.firstNonNull(table.get("AS", "BS"), 0) + 123);
System.out.println(table);
// prints: {AS={BS=123, X=2}}
```

On the other hand, if you don't really need `Table` interface and/or counting is more important to you (and numbers are not negative), consider using `Map<String, Multiset<String>`. Null checks will be more painful when getting multiset, but adding elements will be easier (because of [`Multiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v18.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html)'s capabilities):

```
Map<String, Multiset<String>> mapWithMultiset = new HashMap<>();
// create new multiset to be put as value
HashMultiset<String> x = HashMultiset.create();
x.add("X", 2);
mapWithMultiset.put("AS", x);

// this feels dirty
if (!mapWithMultiset.containsKey("AS")) {
  mapWithMultiset.put("AS", HashMultiset.<String>create());
}
mapWithMultiset.get("AS").add("BS", 123);

System.out.println(mapWithMultiset);
// prints: {AS=[BS x 123, X x 2]}
```

---

It seems like you really need something like `MultisetMultimap` aka `BagMultimap` which:

1. **does not exist in Guava**,
2. would save you the dirty stuff.

It **could** look like this, although the naming would get tricky and usage of put / add methods from `Map` / `Collection` would be somehow confusing (**explicit disclaimer: there's no such thing as `MultisetMultimap`**):

```
MultisetMultimap<String, String> multisetMultimap = HashMultisetMultimap.create();
multisetMultimap.add("AS", "X", 2);
multisetMultimap.add("AS", "BS", 123);

System.out.println(mapWithMultiset);
// should print: {AS=[BS x 123, X x 2]}
```

(If you're interested in this solution, you should go with the [new issue on Github](https://github.com/google/guava/issues). And maybe some Guava dev could answer if there's something like this in Guava internally in Google.)

Answer (score 2):

What came to my mind is a `LoadingCache<StringPair, AtomicInteger>`.

Key is:

```
   public final class StringPair {
       private final String key1, key2;
       // + constructor, hashCode, equals
   }
```

I would create it as such...

```
 LoadingCache<StringPair, AtomicInteger> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .build(
       new CacheLoader<StringPair, AtomicInteger>() {
         public AtomicInteger load(StringPair key) {
           return new AtomicInteger(0);
         }
       });
```

then...

```
 AtomicInteger value = cache.get(new StringPair("AB", "AB"));
 value.addAndGet(123);
```

or

```
cache.get(new StringPair("AB", "AB")).addAndGet(123)
```

In this pattern, you only do the lookup once and the update is very efficient as it doesn't have to traverse the map again. You are not really using the cache as a cache but just a loading map.

As long as you don't need to access the map with just the first key, I think this would work well.

Comment: This approach is OK as well, but I cleaned up your code, I hope you don't mind. If it isn't supposed to be used concurrently, I'd also set [`CacheBuilder#concurrencyLevel(int)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v18.0/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#concurrencyLevel(int)) to 1.

Comment: @Xaerxess I don't mind. Thanks for the fixes and concurrency suggestion. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you are asking.

But you can refactor your code like this.

```
Integer val = table.get("AS", "BS");
val = val == null ? 123 : (val + 123);
table.put("AS", "BS", val);
```